# Quickblox. How to switch from voice to video call and vice versa

Tags: android, video-streaming, quickblox

We need some mechanism to support switching between voice/video call without interruptions. I haven't found any useful info in the docs about this. If this feature unsupported by quickblox, we basically need to communicate during video-call to give to know our opponent that we have switched from voice to video mode. Is there any advice?

Can I communicate over XMPP protocol during calls?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in 2 ways:
 - start video call and disable video stream in any moment.
 - make recall every time you have to switch. - create new QBRTCSession every time. Refer to https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Session_management.

Off course you can communicate over chat during call. Video chat & chat modules work independently. But you can't use Video chat without chat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did as you've suggested. Now I'm working on case when user can leave video-call activity and go back to it, I've checked quickblox sample but they just disable back button, maybe do you know how to do that?